# the result of total_balance is zero why in sql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO transaction (account_name,dates,debit,credit ,total_balance)
VALUES('$account_name',curdate(),$debit,$credit,total_balance=$debit+$credit)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE debit = debit + VALUES(debit), credit = credit + VALUES(credit)
```

this is query i don't know why the balance is shown zero in the total balance column can any body change the query ?

```
Id  Account_name    Date         Debit  Credit  Total_balance
21  revenue     2014-05-05        80      55    0
23  expense     2014-05-05       48000  90000   0
28  a/p         2014-05-05        800   1000    0
```

Comment: How does the resulting query with actual values look like?

Comment: Doh!  Don't store the result of a calculation in the DB when the values used in the calculation are already stored there!

Comment: @AbraCadaver there is one except I have for this rule, when the method you use to calculate it may change and you need to record the values used for historical purposes.

Comment: i want to calculate the total balance of each individual account that is the total of debit+credit

Comment: Store the values and calculate the balance when you need it, maybe when you select or display.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i have calculated the not in sql but in php code but it's creating a problem ..

Comment: string 'INSERT INTO transaction (account_name,dates,debit,credit,total_balance)

    VALUES('cg',curdate(),5000,400,{(5000+400)})

ON DUPLICATE KEY

UPDATE debit = debit + VALUES(debit), credit = credit + VALUES(credit)'  @Gumbo

Comment: `SELECT account_name,dates,debit,credit,(debit+credit) AS balance FROM transaction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, instead:

```
"INSERT INTO transaction (account_name,dates,debit,credit,total_balance)
    VALUES('$account_name',curdate(),$debit,$credit,($debit+$credit))
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE debit = debit + VALUES(debit), credit = credit + VALUES(credit)"
```

Comment: Like Gumbo said, please output the resulting string before it gets sent to SQL.

Comment: Also, AbraCadaver has good advice, to not store the total but calculate it on the fly.